# Where is my Ebook that I just bought from Amazon Kindle to my PC?

Tags: kindle

I am new to Amazon Kindle ebooks. I am using my computer to read Kindle ebooks. I am using Kindle-for-Pc software. I just downloaded an ebook, but I cannot find it anywhere. I need to find it so that I can backup in my flash drive, in case something happens to the computer. I can perfectly read the book from the Kindle-for-Pc program, but I need to find the actual ebook, since it was not free and I don't want to lose it.

Comment: This answer provides some great insight and help too: https://askubuntu.com/a/1012193/327339

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Amazon's Kindle for PC reader saves a copy of your books to your hard drive, once you download them. Note that you have to download them from the cloud; new books aren't downloaded to a device unless (1) you told Amazon to send that book to that device or (2) you downloaded the book from the app on that device.

**By default, the books are saved in this folder:**

```
C:\Users\YOURUSERNAME\AppData\Local\Amazon\Kindle\application\content
```

Replace `YOURUSERNAME` with your Windows username.

**Typically, you will have two files per book: a `.apnx` and a `.azw`. Backup both of them.** You may want to consider an automated backup service to backup these and your other files.

Comment: What is **downloading from cloud**? How is it different from normal download? Do you mean that the ebook is downloaded temporarily on the computer and then gets deleted every time I turn the computer off?

Comment: Can I read the ebooks offline or do I have to stay connected to the internet whenever I want to read any ebook?

Comment: @Raj I just mean downloading it from Amazon; you have to download it in the app before you can read it on the PC. That's a one-time thing. Once you have downloaded it, the book will stay on your computer, and you can read it online or offline.

Comment: Nope, not in that folder! Any other location suggestions?

Comment: What's the directory for Linux Ubuntu?

Comment: This answer seems to no longer apply to Windows too by the way, as the "C:\Users\YOURUSERNAME\AppData\Local\Amazon" folder doesn't exist (on Windows 8.1 at least).

Answer (score 15):

I have Windows 10 and also use the PC software. Mine are stored in my "Documents" folder in subfolder "My Kindle Content". That would ordinarily be "%HOMEPATH%\Documents\My Kindle Content", but I have changed the location of my Documents folder to another drive.

On the Kindle app's toolbar go to "Tools|Options..." and click on the "Content" tab. Here you will see the location of your files along with a button giving you the option to change that location.
[image]

Comment: this worked for me

Comment: The option to change folder is greyed out for me.

Answer (score 6):

I found mine (on Windows 10) in

```
C:\Users\YOURUSERNAME\Documents\My Kindle Content\
```

There's a sub-folder for each downloaded book, containing the .azw and .azw.res files (didn't see a .apnx file).